# How to display multiple keys or 'chords' for a MenuItem on Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, menuitem

I am trying to display multiple key combinations to a MenuItem in cocoa. This is most commonly known as "chords".

For example I want to add a menu item that looks like: 
"Action1   Control K, F" or "MenuItem2     K,L"

Would this be possible in Objective-C through the standard API? I've looked around and the closest thing to this on MacOS would be using custom views. Would it be the way to go for allowing this functionality?

Comment: Are users supposed to type Control-K then, without Control, F? Or Control-K then Control-F? Or hold down Control while simultaneously(?!) pressing K and F? Why would you choose such a UI?

Comment: Because you can already do this on Windows apps, no need to go over why. It can be useful for certain actions to have the users press a combination then another. Or even 2 keys in sequence without any modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard API does not support handling chords, thus it does not allow setting chords as key equivalent and thus it also cannot display a chord as a key equivalent.

If you need that functionality, you need to implement entirely yourself. Just make your own NSView object and assign it to the `view` property of `NSMenuItem`. As documented, you will then have to draw everything yourself:

> A menu item with a view does not draw its title, state, font, or other
>   standard drawing attributes, and assigns drawing responsibility entirely
>   to the view. Keyboard equivalents and type-select continue to use the key
>   equivalent and title as normal.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514835-view?language=objc

Whether this is a normal `NSView` filled with subviews, created either programmatically or even loaded from a NIB file, or whether this is a subclass of `NSView` drawing everything itself is up to you, all these variations will actually work. Usually it's easiest to use a NIB file and build you menu look in interface builder and using autolayout.

Yet keep in mind that this breaks Apple Human Interface guidelines. It violates the users expectation as all his other apps don't offer anything comparable since in macOS a menu item has one key equivalent or it has none. It also breaks the ability of users to customize the key equivalent the way he is used to do this for all other applications (System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts).

Generally you should not replace system standard UI with your own UI unless you really have a very good reason for doing so, as that always breaks users expectations, certain system functionality won't work as expected (e.g. accessibility features) and it destroys the uniform look and feel of the system. Also it breaks system automatic, as you can see in macOS 10.14 (Mojave) where all system standard UI automatically supports dark mode, so if you used only standard UI, your app supports dark mode without any modification, yet all custom UI needs to be customized again for dark mode.

Comment: Would it be possible to override the view of the existing Menu Items such as Undo/Redo etc?

Comment: Undo/Redo are just normal MenuItems, you can even delete them if your app does't want to offer that functionality. They are just pre-created by Interface Builder for new apps can call pre-defined methods that you could also call from your code. There is absolutely nothing special or different about them. You can make you own menu item, give it any name you like, any key equivalent you like and make it call the undo function and it will behave like Undo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to use a custom view. `NSMenuItem` only displays the first character of its `keyEquivalent`.